# Django login - missing 1 required positional argument - Not Actually missing

Tags: django, django-authentication

I built a custom view in order to login the user with his email, not with his username. Anyway, I end up using the included `authenticate` and `login` methods contained in `django.contrib.auth`. Not sure which is the problem with this code:

```
class LoginUsuario(FormView):
    """
    Hace login con el email
    """
    template = "perfiles/login.html"
    form_class = FormularioLogin
    success_url = reverse_lazy("cliente:mi_perfil")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        correo = form.cleaned_data['correo_electronico']
        password = form.cleaned_data['contrasena']

        usuario = User.objects.get(email=correo)
        user = authenticate(username=usuario.username, password=password)
        login(self.request, user)

        return super(LoginUsuario, self).form_valid(form)
```

I get the error:

> login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: Are you sure the error refers to this file? code looks good to me really

Comment: Just found the error :/ . Sry my fault. The urlpattern pointing to this view was  writen as if it was a method and not a class based view. When I changed it and added an `as_view()` method, the error dissapeared.